# win32api SendMessage wont work outside of WM_CREATE

Tags: c++, winapi, sendmessage

So, i was working on a "larger" project, and suddenly got strange issues with a simple sendmessage command.. So i created a new project, That just creates a edit control, and a timer. Everytime the timer ticks it should put out "test" to the edit control. But it never happens..

Ive tried the timer with a  messagebox, and it works. Also the sendmessage work, if i put it in WM_CREATE.. Why is this?

```html
// 785tyughj.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "785tyughj.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
#define ID_FLSPEED 1
#define ID_TIMER 2




// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;        // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];     // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];   // the main window class name
HWND FLSPEED;
// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM    MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL    InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);








int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
 UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
 UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

  // TODO: Place code here.
 MSG msg;
 HACCEL hAccelTable;
 

 // Initialize global strings
 LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
 LoadString(hInstance, IDC_MY785TYUGHJ, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
 MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

 // Perform application initialization:
 if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
 {
  return FALSE;
 }

 hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MY785TYUGHJ));

 // Main message loop:
 while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
 {
  if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
  {
   TranslateMessage(&msg);
   DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
 }

 return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
//  COMMENTS:
//
//    This function and its usage are only necessary if you want this code
//    to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'
//    function that was added to Windows 95. It is important to call this function
//    so that the application will get 'well formed' small icons associated
//    with it.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
 WNDCLASSEX wcex;

 wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

 wcex.style   = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
 wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
 wcex.cbClsExtra  = 0;
 wcex.cbWndExtra  = 0;
 wcex.hInstance  = hInstance;
 wcex.hIcon   = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MY785TYUGHJ));
 wcex.hCursor  = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
 wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
 wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MY785TYUGHJ);
 wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
 wcex.hIconSm  = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

 return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}






//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
 int wmId, wmEvent;
 PAINTSTRUCT ps;
 HDC hdc;
 

 switch (message)
 {
 case WM_CREATE:
  
  {
  HWND FLSPEED=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
  L"EDIT",
  L"speed",
  WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
  50,
  50,
  125,
  25,
  hWnd,
  (HMENU)ID_FLSPEED,
  GetModuleHandle(NULL),
  NULL);
  

  SetTimer (hWnd,ID_TIMER,1000,NULL);

  
  }

  

 case WM_TIMER:
  
  {
  SendMessageA(FLSPEED,WM_SETTEXT,NULL,(LPARAM)"test");
  


  break;
  }


 case WM_COMMAND:
  wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
  wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
  // Parse the menu selections:
  switch (wmId)
  {
  case IDM_ABOUT:
   DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
   break;
  case IDM_EXIT:
   DestroyWindow(hWnd);
   break;
  default:
   return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
  }
  break;
 case WM_PAINT:
  hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
  // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
  EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
  break;
 case WM_DESTROY:
  PostQuitMessage(0);
  break;


 

  
  


 default:
  
  return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
 }
 return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
 UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
 switch (message)
 {
 case WM_INITDIALOG:
  return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

 case WM_COMMAND:
  if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
  {
   EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
   return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
  }
  break;
 }
 return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: `HWND FLSPEED=CreateWindowEx` you are creating a new FLSPEED that masks the global FLSPEED. get rid of the HWND so you actually change the value of the global.

Comment: @drescherjm Oh yes!! How could i miss that.. Actually, i had commented that out, on the larger project, came back today, wondered why the heck i did that, and uncommented it. Haha! Thank you very very much for this. Im not sure how to credit you for this? Do you need to post an "answer"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line is the problem:

```
HWND FLSPEED=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
L"EDIT",
L"speed",
WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
50,
50,
125,
25,
hWnd,
(HMENU)ID_FLSPEED,
GetModuleHandle(NULL),
NULL);
```

In that line you are creating a new local FLSPEED that masks the global FLSPEED. To fix that get rid of the HWND so that you are not declaring a new variable and that you actually change the value of the global.

```
FLSPEED=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
L"EDIT",
L"speed",
WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
50,
50,
125,
25,
hWnd,
(HMENU)ID_FLSPEED,
GetModuleHandle(NULL),
NULL);
```